# C# winform Filter combobox items based on datagridview values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a combobox called `cmbCaseRemain` its data populated from datatable by code

```
cmbCaseRemain.DataSource = ce.GET_ALL_CASEREMAIN();
cmbCaseRemain.DisplayMember = "caseRemain";
cmbCaseRemain.ValueMember = "idCaseRemain";
```

and I have a datagridview called `dgv_CaseRemain` gets its data from another datatable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ce.GET_ALL_CASEREMAIN_FILTER(Convert.ToInt32(txtidCase.Text));
dgv_CaseRemain.DataSource = dt;
```

I'm using the combobox to add items to the datagrid view ... and i want after every adding to filter the items in the combobox so the user can't add the same value twice ... so I created a stored procedure with a parameter

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[FILTER_CMB_CASEREMAIN]
    @ID int
AS
    SELECT 
        [idCaseRemain], [caseRemain]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[tblCaseRemain]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        tblCase_Link_Remain ON idCaseRemain = idCaseRemain_L
    WHERE 
        [idCaseRemain] <> @ID;
```

and using a code to pass the parameter which filter the combobox when i click on it

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ce.FILTER_CMB_CASEREMAIN(Convert.ToInt32(this.dgv_CaseRemain.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value));

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    cmbCaseRemain.DisplayMember = "caseRemain";
    cmbCaseRemain.ValueMember = "idCaseRemain";
    cmbCaseRemain.DataSource = dt;
}
```

but I got an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thank you

( sorry for my bad english :-) )

Comment: what is "ce" ? " ce.GET_ALL_CASEREMAIN();" in this code ce might be null, Are you init. the ce object?

Comment: "ce" the source of datatable ... its not null

        `public DataTable GET_ALL_CASEREMAIN()
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt = DAL.SelectData("GET_ALL_CASEREMAIN", null);

            DAL.close();
            return dt;
        }`

Comment: debug your app, see on which line its failing. This is very common error, it happen when you access object without init. My next guess is "this.dgv_CaseRemain.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value" line. Plz do debug and find the exact line. This is the best way to solve your issue. No one can guess your entire code.

Comment: i'll give it a try .... thank you

Comment: the error in that line
            `dt = ce.FILTER_CMB_CASEREMAIN(Convert.ToInt32(this.dgv_CaseRemain.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value));`

Answer (score 1):

ok. Got it. As I said, it was error on that line. Use below code. Below I add the validation to check the null value.

```
int n = 0;
DataTable dt;
if (this.dgv_CaseRemain.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value != null)
{
    if (int.TryParse(this.dgv_CaseRemain.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out n))
    {
        dt = ce.FILTER_CMB_CASEREMAIN(n);
    }
}
if (dt!=null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{

    cmbCaseRemain.DisplayMember = "caseRemain";
    cmbCaseRemain.ValueMember = "idCaseRemain";
    cmbCaseRemain.DataSource = dt;
}
```